# DFS search that returns "not found" or distance

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

Assuming I've the following code:

```
    public static int dfsDistance(List<List<Integer>> graph, int current, int searchValue, int steps, BitSet visited) {
        if (current == searchValue) {
            return steps;   
        }
        
        for (int neighbor : graph.get(current)) {
            if (visited.get(neighbor)) {
                continue;   
            }
            visited.set(neighbor);
            int cStep = dfs(graph, neighbor, searchValue, steps + 1, visited);
            if (cStep > -1) {
                return cStep;   
            }
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
```

Is this the common approach? The only other way I could see is replacing it with `Optional<Integer>`.  How should I properly return "not found" or distance?

Comment: Generally speaking, associating -1 with "not found" is a common idiom in Java. For example the String.indexOf(char) uses it. Since your use of primitive types already takes care of the possibility of null values, replacing it with an Optional is an artificial complication and goes a bit against the purpose of Optionals: to represent the possibility of null value in code instead of comments or annotations.

Comment: `[I can see using a specially interpreted int value or an] Optional<Integer>` Then, there is `Number`/`integer`, with `null` a plausible value for *none*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your version is this:

```
visited.set(neighbor);
```

Above, if `neighbor` is a large integer (say 100_000_000), the `BitSet` will have to create a huge array under the hood to accommodate 100_000_000+ bits. One workaround is to use a simple `java.util.HashSet<Integer>`.

Also, the `steps` can be renamed to `depth`. (Actually, you could give the data more specific names, see below.)

**Alternative implementation**

I had this in mind:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public class DFS {
    
    public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    
    public static int getDistance(List<List<Integer>> graph,
                                  Integer currentNode,
                                  Integer goalNode) {
        return getDistanceImpl(
                graph, 
                new HashSet<>(), 
                currentNode, 
                goalNode,
                0);
    }
    
    private static int getDistanceImpl(List<List<Integer>> graph,
                                       Set<Integer> visitedSet,
                                       Integer currentNode,
                                       Integer goalNode,
                                       int depth) {
        if (Objects.equals(currentNode, goalNode)) {
            return depth;
        }
        
        for (Integer neighborNode : graph.get(currentNode)) {
            if (visitedSet.add(neighborNode)) {
                int tentativeDepth = 
                        getDistanceImpl(
                                graph, 
                                visitedSet, 
                                neighborNode, 
                                goalNode, 
                                depth + 1);

                if (tentativeDepth != NOT_FOUND) {
                    return tentativeDepth;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return NOT_FOUND;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A 4-node cycle:
        List<List<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<>();
        graph.add(new ArrayList<>());
        graph.add(new ArrayList<>());
        graph.add(new ArrayList<>());
        graph.add(new ArrayList<>());
        graph.get(0).add(1);
        graph.get(1).add(2);
        graph.get(2).add(3);
        graph.get(3).add(0);
        
        System.out.println(getDistance(graph, 0, 3));
    }
}
```

```
for (int neighbor : graph.get(current)) {

}
```

Above, `graph.get(x)` will return an `Integer`; thus, you spend some CPU cycles in autounboxing that `Integer` to an `int`.

Finally, your version does not allow negative graph nodes since `visited.set(-1)` will throw.

Answer (score 2):

Although associating -1 with "not found" is a common idiom for some java programmers but I prefer using Optional instead of it. The Optional class forces you to think about the case when the value is not present.
Assume someone uses your code to calculate the sum of distances. If he/she does not read your method body, can't understand what happens if the searchValue is not found; So the result would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using if statement just for continue looks not good, would change it to:

```
if (!visited.get(neighbor)) {     
            visited.set(neighbor);
            int cStep = dfs(graph, neighbor, searchValue, steps + 1, visited);
            if (cStep > -1) {
                return cStep;   
            }
        }
```